# Get Smartsheet Data via API and create Wordpress html Post?

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, smartsheet-api

I'm researching the possibility of styled reporting on Wordpress, fed by Smartsheet data. My idea is to on click or even on frequency/date, get grid content from SmartSheet API and publish to a Wordpress post. I want the columns/cells/rows to output as html objects (ideally integration code allows me to create classes based on column and/or cell content logic) so I can style with CSS.

As someone with strong technical skills but no deep coding ability, am I being crazy to attempt self-teaching and building this? I feel like logically it seems pretty possible. If it is I would learn and execute myself.

Thoughts on how feasible, potential roadblocks?

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from Smartsheet via its API into a Wordpress page is achievable. The biggest hurdle I can see you running into is since the Smartsheet API doesn't have support for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you won't be able to make requests to the Smartsheet API directly from the page on the front end. You'll need to build out some back end code that lives on your server that interacts with the Smartsheet API and your Wordpress site calls that code to get the data it needs.